# Thermal state of free fermions in contact with a reservoir at temperature $T$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, many-body

Without loss of generality and for simplicity, consider a two fermion Hamiltonian
$$
H = \lambda (c_1^\dagger c_2 + c_2^\dagger c_1),
$$
where $c_i$ are fermionic ops, i.e. a hopping Hamiltonian. We can diagonalise $H$,
$$
H = (+\lambda)f_1^\dagger f_1 +(-\lambda)f_2^\dagger f_2
$$
with
$$
f_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(c_1 +c_2) \quad f_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(c_1-c_2).
$$
In the computational basis of $f$'s we have 4 eigenstates, as expected:
$$
|00\rangle_f, E_{00}=0 \quad |01\rangle_f, E_{01}=+\lambda \quad |10\rangle_f, E_{10}=-\lambda \quad |11\rangle_f, E_{11}=0.
$$

When one resorts to the definition of the thermal density matrix
$$
\rho = \frac{\exp(-\beta H)}{\text{Tr}(\exp(-\beta H))},
$$
in the eigenbasis (computational basis of $f$'s) this is simply
$$
\rho = \frac{1}{\sum_n e^{-\beta E_n}}
\sum_n e^{-\beta E_n}|E_n\rangle \langle E_n|.
$$
Plugging the above results
$$
\rho = \frac{1}{2+e^{-\lambda \beta}+e^{\lambda \beta}}(|00\rangle \langle 00|_f+ e^{-\lambda\beta}|01\rangle \langle 01|_f +e^{\lambda \beta}|10\rangle \langle 10|_f +|11\rangle \langle 11|_f).
$$
But I want the final answer in the original computational basis of the $c$'s, using
$$
|00\rangle_f = |00\rangle_c \quad |01\rangle_f = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|01\rangle_c + |10\rangle_c) \quad |10\rangle_f = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|01\rangle_c - |10\rangle_c) \quad |11\rangle_f = |11\rangle_c
$$
we yield (in matrix form)
$$
\rho = \frac{1}{2+\cosh(\beta \lambda)} \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&\cosh(\beta \lambda)&\sinh(\beta \lambda)&0\\0&\sinh(\beta \lambda)&\cosh(\beta\lambda)&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
**But I believe it should have been**
$$
\rho = \frac{1}{1+2 e^{-\beta \lambda} +e^{-2\beta \lambda}}\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&e^{-\beta \lambda}&0&0\\0&0&e^{-\beta\lambda}&0\\0&0&0&e^{-2\beta \lambda}\end{bmatrix}
$$
which, just by looking at it, is the thermal state of a 2D fermionic system with energies $\{0,\lambda, \lambda, 2\lambda\}$, i.e. each particle has the same energy ($H=\lambda (c^\dagger_1 c_1 + c_2^\dagger c_2)$). Im really confused…

Comment: Your calculation is correct, but the last formula appears from nowhere... it is not even consistent with the eigenenergies that you found.